# Usage of Alias and Community Nickname

Tags: user-management

May I know what are the usages of Community Nickname and Alias fields? Where are they used effectively?

Also, Community Nickname is unique but not Alias. Thus, 2 users can have the same alias. Is there any reason why Alias is also not unique?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Salesforce [documentation](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/user_fields.htm) on User fields:

> **Alias:** Short name to identify user on list pages, reports, and other
> pages where the entire name does not fit. Up to eight characters are
> allowed in this field.
>
> **Community Nickname:** Name used to identify this
> user in a community. Up to 40 alphanumeric characters are allowed;
> standard users can edit this field.

I can't answer why Alias is not unique, but I personally think it is an oversight and keep them unique in my org.